# how to dispatch own events to controls to simulate mouseclicks in c#?

Tags: c#, events, mouse, mouseevent, simulate

Is it possible in c# to dispatch own events to controls?

I mean, like you can do in java:

```
MouseEvent leftClick = new MouseEvent(image, MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED,
0, 0, 100, 100, 1, false, MouseEvent.BUTTON1);

image.dispatchEvent(leftClick);
```

Comment: What app architecture are you targeting? Windows Forms, WPF, Silerlight?

Answer (score 0):

Events in C# work a little differently.  Instead of dispatching an event to the object, you subscribe to an event the object has available and provide a delegate.  See [Events (C# vs. Java)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228499%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) for reference.  However, if you want to run the code attached to an event, you can call the delegate directly, but I think most people would consider this bad form.  It may be better to have a method which performs the action and call it from both the delegate and wherever you are wanting to simulate the click event from.

```
 SomeControl.LeftMouseButtonDown += new LeftMouseButtonDown(SomeControl_LeftMouseButtonDown);

 protected void SomeControl_LeftMouseButtonDown(object sender, EventArgs e) //Might be typed EventArgs instead of generic.
 {
     //Run some code or call some method.
 }
```

Preferably, you would use the Click event instead of the LeftMouseButtonDown as the Click event is thrown on LeftMouseButtonDown and LeftMouseButtonUp when they occur consecutively.

Are you working with a control that does not have a LeftMouseButtonDown or Click event?  If so, you will need to write your own control that inherits from that control and write your own event.

Also, it would help if you provided some details over which .NET technology you are using (WPF, WinForms, ASP.NET, Silverlight, etc) as each has a different control set.  It may also be helpful to know which control you are using from that technology.

Hope this helps though!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the `MouseController` for [NUnitForms](http://nunitforms.sourceforge.net/index.html).  Its designed to work with Windows Forms and simulates the events by placing the events into the Windows event queue.

You can view the source at http://nunitforms.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/nunitforms/trunk/nunitforms/source/NUnitForms/MouseController.cs?revision=69&view=markup